# What is the delimiter name of a C# project file?

Tags: c#, solution, vcproj

What is the file name "delimiter? name of a C# project file?

I am not sure if "delimiter" is the right term.  A solutions file ends as ".sln".  How does a project file end in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "file extension".  The file extension for a project file is `.csproj`

Comment: Please see this follow-up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968102/what-are-the-other-possible-names-of-project-files-in-c-other-than-cproj

Answer (score 2):

it will be `.csproj`

`.csproj.user`  will be the Visual Studio Project User Options File

Comment: Please see this follow-up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968102/what-are-the-other-possible-names-of-project-files-in-c-other-than-cproj

Answer (score 0):

C# Project files have the suffix:  `.csproj`

Comment: Please see this follow-up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968102/what-are-the-other-possible-names-of-project-files-in-c-other-than-cproj