# What are the other possible names of project files in C# other than .cproj?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, project, vcproj

.cproj is not the only name of the project file.  My solution says there are 5 projects but only three .cproj files are seen.  What is the file extinsion of other project files/?  THe icon that represents the other two look different as well:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps take a screen shot of the project folder from Windows Explorer, and we can point out the project files for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an ASP.NET web app, but I'm not seeing the code symbol in the lower right corner (normally you'd have a C# or VB symbol)

Comment: if it is a ASP.NET web app what is the file extension of the project file?  Is there one?

Comment: it would be in a .csproj given youre using c#

Comment: there is no .cproj file associated with these two "projects"  thre is only an .asmx file, a web.config file andsome DLL's that were imported into the "project".  I think from the pop-up window that comes when you right-mouse-click on the projects that they are ASP.NET project since one option is "Add ASP.Net folder" which does not appear with the three projects that have associated .cproj files.